# Creating a list of functions in python (python function closure bug?)

Tags: python, function, closures

I understand functional programming well. I want to create a list of functions that each selects a different element of a list. I have reduced my problem to a simple example. Surely this is a Python bug:

```
fun_list = []
for i in range(5):
    def fun(e):
        return e[i]
    fun_list.append(fun)

mylist = range(10)
print([f(mylist) for f in fun_list])
```

"Obviously" it should return [0,1,2,3,4].
It however returns [4, 4, 4, 4, 4].  How can I coerce Python to do the right thing? (Hasn't this been noticed before? Or am I just being thick?)

This is Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 25 2014, 11:07:05)

Thanks,
David

Comment: when the inner function `fun` runs the value of i is 4.  The line `return e[i]` runs when you call the function, not when you define the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I coerce Python to do the right thing?

Here is one approach:

```
fun_list = []
for i in range(5):
    def fun(e, _ndx=i):
        return e[_ndx]
    fun_list.append(fun)

mylist = range(10)
print([f(mylist) for f in fun_list])
```

This works because the default value for `_ndx` is evaluated and saved when the `def` statement for `fun` is executed.  (In python, `def` statements are *executed*.)

Answer (score 2):

> Surely this is a Python bug...

This is a misunderstanding of scopes. Since all five instances of `fun()` are defined in the same scope, they will all have the same value of all names in that scope, including `i`. In order to fix this you need to separate the value used from the scope containing the loop itself. This can be done by defining the function within a completely different scope.

```
fun_list = []

def retfun(i):
  def fun(e):
    return e[i]
  return fun

for i in range(5):
  fun_list.append(retfun(i))

mylist = range(10)
print([f(mylist) for f in fun_list])
```

Comment: It is not a misunderstanding of scopes. I'd expect the function to be evaluated in the current environment; not some one in the future. The reasonable approach is for the function to be associated with a *copy* of the current environment, not the environment after all of the values have changed. That is why we define functions in particular contexts....

Comment: If it was given a *copy* of the current scope then there would be no way for it to work with non-local scopes since values in those scopes would never change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
fun_list = []
for i in range(5):
    fun_list.append(itemgetter(i))

mylist = range(10)
print([f(mylist) for f in fun_list])
```

In your case, you are assigning a function to all elements referencing a global `i` with the value of `i` at the time of the call, which is 4 for all calls. You need some sort of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Same without the `itemgetter`:

```
def indexer(i): return lambda y: y[i]

fun_list = []
for i in range(5):
    fun_list.append(indexer(i))

mylist = range(10)
print([f(mylist) for f in fun_list])
```